# How to change the default value of padding of all ionic pages?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I want to change the default value of padding in ionic !

for example: I use this way to change the value for each page

```
<ion-content padding style="padding:5px;">
</ion-content>
```

So, Is possible to change the value of padding for all pages without use style many times?

Comment: Yes it is possible just go and the required styles in your app.scss it will be applied globally

Comment: I tried but no changes, maybe there is some thing wrong in my scss codes, can you write me the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Usually I do it this way :
ion-content {
    padding : 5px
}

Comment: no problem using this way, but the default value of "padding" word when I use it with ion-card, ion-item, or any thing else is bigger than I want. So I wrote this question to get the solution for "padding" word (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be by looking for the `Ionic SASS variable` that defines the padding of each component (**[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)**), and override it in the `variables.scss` file.

So for example, if you want to change the padding of the `ion-content` in the entire app, you'd need to override the `$content-padding` SASS property:

```
$content-padding: 10px; /* The default is 16px */
```

Please also notice that if you want you can change it for a particular platform if you don't want to change it for all:

```
$content-ios-padding: 10px;
$content-md-padding: 12px;
$content-wp-padding: 14px;
```

If you want to change the padding of the `ion-card`, just search for the SASS property related to that padding/margin of `ion-card` components, and override it in the `variables.scss` file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok at first i didn't get what you actually meant if you want to override the default padding attribute value you need to go to 
src/theme/variables.scss file, and just add a new value to the file:

```
$content-padding (
  padding : 5px
)
```

Comment: I solved problem using this way *[padding] {padding: 10px !important;}